# can ping Linux1-Win-Linux2 but cannot Linux1-Linux2

Tags: linux, networking, virtualbox, ping

At home, I have a Windows 7 host with a Linux1 VirtualBox client, and a Linux2 desktop.

I can ping both Linux from Windows 7. I can also ping Windows 7 from both Linux. But I cannot ping any Linux from another Linux.

I seems very strange to me. Anybody can help me?

**EDIT:**

Both my Windows and Linux machines are connected by wireless internet. I only have one wireless router.

All of them have ip address like this: 192.168.1.XXX.

Comment: Strange. I can ping my own Linux machines. Your Linux desktop may be on a different subnet than your Windows 7 host if Windows 7 is wireless.  Is your Windows 7 machine wireless and so somehow isolated from the main network?

Comment: @John please see the Edit above.

Comment: If all the machines are on the same subnet, then you may have implemented Linux firewalls to prevent access. I have not this and I can easily ping any Linux machine from the other Linux machine.